# LaunchDemon is not loading from shell script

Tags: bash, macos, shell, launch, launchctl

I have a small shell script which loads a launchctl **com.skull.tst.plist**. But when i run script its not loading launchctl. I am getting echo match and running script with sudo.

When i copy  `sudo /bin/launchctl load -wF /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.skull.tst.plist` in terminal it works fine and loads.

why it's not loading with shell scripts?

```
#!/bin/sh

ve="1013"

if  [ "$ve" == "1013" ]; then
    echo "match"
    /bin/launchctl load -wF /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.skull.tst.plist
else
    exit
fi
```

Comment: your `ve` variable doesn't match the condition to execute the if-statement, so it just exits.

Comment: @meatspace yes it was a miss type i have correct it. but still not working.